Launched app windows not showing after upgrading to 24.04
Ever since I upgraded to 24.04.1 I am unable to do anything because any apps or even Settings I launch doesn't show the App/Settings window.  It is like the window is invisible.  I can't get to Settings or launch the terminal.
I am running Ubuntu desktop on a MAC Pro with 32GB of ECC RAM, 2x XEON E5520 Processors, 512SSDn. I don't recall the graphics card, but I think it is an Nvidia that came with the Mac Pro. It's connected to the monitor via thunderbolt to HDMI.
I've tried different monitorw, cables (new), complete shutdown and reboots.  I tried to remote desktop to it, but apparently I never turned on that feature on that computer.
I tried booting to a live session from a USB stick to Try Ubuntu, but when I open Files the system locks up. I'm wondering if the upgrade got corrupted.  How do I go about fixing the installation without losing my settings?
